# JAVA Check for specific format of a String?

Tags: java, regex, string, int

I need to check if the trimmed version of a user-entered String has the following format:

(integer,integer)

How can I do this? I was considering using a regex, but I'm not too familiar with them. For example, I don't know how I would be able to limit the inputted number to the maximum value for an integer.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

for example (5,2)

`\(-?\d+,-?\d+\)`  use this regex expression

Comment: This doesn't work for the input (2147483648,-2147483649)

Comment: @phflack u've got a space in between (2147483648, -2147483649)

Comment: Was busy focusing on the numbers, not the spacing, fixed it (and still should not work)

Comment: @phflack just checked it on regexr, it's working

Comment: Now test converting both numbers to ints, they can't be ints and your regex is saying they can, see the contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "(12345,67890)";
if(input.charAt(0) != '(' || input.charAt(input.length() - 1) != ')')
    return false;
input = input.substring(1, input.length() - 2);
String[] numbers = input.split(",");
if(numbers.length != 2)
    return false;
try
{
    Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
    Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
    return false;
}
return true;
```

This will make sure that you can indeed parse both numbers, since otherwise it will throw an exception and return false

Answer (score 0):

public boolean matches(String regex)
Tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression.
 java doc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)

Example :

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "(2147483648,-2147483649)";
    System.out.println(checkInputValidity(input));
  }

  public static boolean checkInputValidity(String input){
    String[] splitInput=null;
    // Motch the pattern
    if(input.matches("\\(-?\\d+,-?\\d+\\)")){
        splitInput = input.split(",");
        int a = 0 ;
        int b = 0 ;
        //Make sure the first part is an integer
        try{
            a = Integer.parseInt(splitInput[0].replace("(",""));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            return false;
        }
        //Make sure the second part is an integer
        try{
            b = Integer.parseInt(splitInput[1].replace(")",""));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

This will output true if it matches, false if not.

Comment: Try testing (2147483648,-2147483649)

Comment: @phflack it does work with that.

Comment: You mean it's returning false as it is supposed to?  Both numbers are invalid ints

Comment: Indeed he asked for ints, good catch Sir :) a parseInt it is then.

Comment: @phflack what about this one ?

Comment: Looks like it should work.  At least now there's two valid, working answers instead of just one